# Parse a cell and return associated values into another cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

In Excel 2016, I am trying to write either an array formula or a vba function to complete the following:

1.) User enters a string (a Project Name) into a cell (Cell D1 in attached example)

2.) Cells in Column B will fill in with the number(s) associated with the Project Name string based on the contents of Column A each separated by commas

Column A contains some number of comma delimited entries. Each entry contains a Project Name and an associated Number separated by a `%` character

For example, the first row in the example image contains three entries:

```
Project1 1234
Project2 2345
Project3 5678
```

This is entered as "Project1%1234,Project2%2345,Project3%5678" in the cell

I have attached an example image that contains a blank version of my problem and below that is what the desired result would be if the user entered `Project1`. I hope this illustrates the problem well but if not I can clarify.

Is this possible to accomplish with an array formula or will this require a user defined function in vba?

[image: example image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible with just an array formula. It's not exactly simple, though.

[image: Worksheet Screenshot]

Array enter (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>) the following formula in `B2` and copy-paste/fill-down the column:

```dart
{=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,LEFT(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A2,$D$1&"%",REPT(" ",LEN(A2))),(ROW(INDEX(B:B,1):INDEX(B:B,LEN(A2)/2))-1)*LEN(A2)+1,LEN(A2))),IFERROR(FIND(",",TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(","&A2&",",$D$1&"%",REPT(" ",LEN(A2))),(ROW(INDEX(B:B,1):INDEX(B:B,LEN(A2)/2))-1)*LEN(A2)+1,LEN(A2))))-1,0)))}
```

---

The prettified formula is as follows:

```dart
{=
TEXTJOIN(
  ",",
  TRUE,
  LEFT(
    TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A2,$D$1&"%",REPT(" ",LEN(A2))),(ROW(INDEX(B:B,1):INDEX(B:B,LEN(A2)/2))-1)*LEN(A2)+1,LEN(A2))),
    IFERROR(
      FIND(
        ",",
        TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(","&A2&",",$D$1&"%",REPT(" ",LEN(A2))),(ROW(INDEX(B:B,1):INDEX(B:B,LEN(A2)/2))-1)*LEN(A2)+1,LEN(A2)))
      )-1,
      0
    )
  )
)}
```

**Explanation:**

The formula works by replacing the project name plus separator in the target string with a long sequence of spaces, and then "splitting" the string up into an array of chunks, each of which begins with the project number of a matched project. That is the output of the `TRIM(…)` functions.

Then the leftmost part of each chunk up to, but not including, the first comma, i.e. the project number, is extracted.

Finally the project numbers are concatenated with the `TEXTJOIN()` function.

The `IFERROR` part of `IFERROR(FIND(",",TRIM(…))-1,0)` is required to remove the errors returned when the `FIND()` function fails, with the resulting null strings being ignored by `TEXTJOIN()`.

**Notes:**

- The prettified formula actually works if entered.

Comment: This is a great alternative to `Regex`

Answer (score 1):

Since I didn't see robinCTS's answer in time I ended up writing a vba function that solves this problem. I figured I would share it even though it's a bit clunky just in case it helps someone with the same problem.

```
Function ParseK(celltxt As String, userin As String) As String
Dim project_name As String
Dim number As String
Dim final_result As String
Dim string_array() As String
ReDim string_array(5)
Dim i As Variant
string_array = Split(celltxt, ",")
For Each i In string_array
    number = Right(i, Len(i) - InStr(i, "%"))
    project_name = Left(i, InStr(i, "%") - 1)
    If InStr(project_name, userin) > 0 Or project_name = userin Then final_result = final_result & number & ","

Next i
ParseK = final_result
End Function
```